# Unable to inspect/debug Qualtrics Javascript code in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug, qualtrics

I have added a very simple javascript/jQuery code in Qualtrics.  It is working fine.  But, for my own understanding and since I might be integrating more complex jQuery codes with Qualtrics in the future, I wanted to examine the flow in Firefox.  I tried both Firebug as well as the browser's inbuilt Web Developer tools, but I am unable to see any navigation into the javascript code.  In fact, Firebug is saying there are no javascript codes.

Following are my firefox and firebug versions:
Firefox 53.0.3
Firebug 2.0.19

Any help will be appreciated.

PS:  My Qualtrics code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
   /*Place Your JavaScript Here*/

   var txtItem =jQuery("#hiddentext");

   if (txtItem.length ) {
        //alert("jquery retrieval worked - DOM element found");

        txtItem.fadeIn(5000);  
        txtItem.css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%", "display": "inline"});

    } else {
        alert("jquery retrieval did not work - DOM element NOT found");
    }
});
```

Comment: Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) and its *Script* panel (besides other things) doesn't work anymore in Firefox 53.

Comment: What do you mean with "unable to see any navigation into the JavaScript code"? Doesn't the script execution stop when you set a breakpoint at the first line of the function, i.e. `var txtItem =jQuery("#hiddentext)");`?

Comment: No, the execution stops somewhere else - in some system code.  Not my code i.e. the var declaration.  Not sure why.  If I continue to do "step over", finally the entire code executes, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug doesn't work anymore.  You'll have to use the built-in developer tools. If you are running under JFE in Qualtrics, add the following command to your script where you want to start stepping through.

```
debugger;
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested.  Using the inbuilt Firefox Web developer tool and the above code added before the "var statement", the execution did halt.  However, it seems I am unable to drill into the above Javascript code even if I continue to step into in the debug mode. I am not sure what is meant by "JFE in Qualtrics".  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint within your script or add a `debugger;` statement where you want the script execution to stop.

If it doesn't stop at the expected line, this may have two reasons:

1. An exception thrown before the execution reaches your line. In that case you should check the console for JavaScript errors. Stopping the script execution on exceptions can be disabled via Debugger settings (little gear icon at the right side of the panel) > *Pause on exceptions*.
2. It is a bug in the Firefox DevTools. In that case you should first check whether this issue can be reproduced in [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org) (which has a new debugger UI). If it can be reproduced there, you should [file a bug report for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Debugger).

Comment: Sebastian - in order to place a breakpoint within my script, I need to be able to access my script in Firefox DevTools.  I am unable to do this.  This is not a regular javascript code within <script></script>.  This is javascript within Qualtrics; and I am unsure where it should appear or where I should look for it in Firefox Devtools.  Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: I never used Qualtrics, though when you press Ctrl+Alt+F or write an `!` within the search field of the DevTools Debugger you can [search within all JavaScript sources for your sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger_(Before_Firefox_52)/How_to/Search_and_filter).

Comment: I tried Chrome.  It works very nicely in Chrome and the debugger statement highlighted and stopped execution at the appropriate place in the code.  I could then step in/step over.  I could locate the code in Firefox with your search suggestion but somehow navigating in the debug mode was not working smoothly.

Comment: That sounds like option 2 of my answer. You should try to reduce your issue to a reproducible test case, create a bug report and attach the test case, so the Firefox DevTools team can fix it.